# Seeking documentation on DEMProcessing from GDAL?

Tags: gdal

I am using python 3.X and I am transforming a DEM (from a raster GeoTIFF file) into a slop tif file.
I am using GDAL and rasterio to do that.

Specifically, I am using the method:

> gdal.DEMProcessing(output, input, 'slope')

My problem is I do not know what is the mathematics and what exact method GDAL uses to calculate the slope. I can't find the answer in the GDAL documentation.

Can anyone can point me to that?

Comment: Two methods are named in the documentation `Use Zevenbergen & Thorne formula, instead of Horn’s formula, to compute slope & aspect. The literature suggests Zevenbergen & Thorne to be more suited to smooth landscapes, whereas Horn’s formula to perform better on rougher terrain`

Comment: If all else fails you can read the code

Answer (score 3):

I was also looking for the DEMProcessing docs. I've found them here:

- [DEMProcessing](https://gdal.org/api/python/osgeo.gdal.html#osgeo.gdal.DEMProcessing)
- [DEMProcessingOptions](https://gdal.org/api/python/osgeo.gdal.html#osgeo.gdal.DEMProcessingOptions)

For the `alg` option:

> `alg` – ‘Horn’ (default) or ‘ZevenbergenThorne’ for hillshade, slope or aspect.